# Mistakes which are made by native English speakers

Tags: grammar, word-usage, usage

Which difficulties do native English speakers face when they learn their mother tongue at school or just in life(especially I'm curious to know about high school when people are already supposed to speak rather literally and correctly)?Maybe there are some grammar issues(like possesive case) or a difficulty with putting emphasises in a correct place?And are there such themes in English which seem to be quite hard to understand even for an educated adult person?For example, were there such cases when even politicians, celebrities or someone from other famous people, for whom English is native, mistook?Could you give some example, please?

Comment: This question is definitely interesting, but too broad.  You could try asking about just one feature of English that you suspect native speakers have difficulty with.  That might get better responses. Anecdotally, I hear people misconjugating irregular verbs.  Specifically, I hear people say things like, "It was *ran* last night" pretty frequently.

Comment: Generally speaking, native speakers of any language have no trouble learning the structure of their language as very young children. What UK and US English speakers learn in school is the written form of the language. The difficulties there arise from the mechanics of writing -- spelling, punctuation, and style. Most people confuse *lie-lay-lain* and *lay-laid-laid*; most people don't bother with the proper use of *who-whom* or the subjunctive mood. And when enough of them persist, the language is considered to have changed to accommodate them.